# Как выровнять ссылки по левому краю внутри списка li?

Tags: ссылки, список

Есть некоторый список li, внутри есть картинки разного размера из-за этого текст ссылок смешается. Задача состоит в том чтобы внутри этого списка выровнять все ссылки по левому краю. Прошу подсказать как хотя бы примерно выровнять текст ссылок? Заранее благодарю.

"

- [image] Текст номер один
- [image] Текст разной длины
- [image]Пусть будет текст
- [image]Какой то текст
- [image]И здесь текст

Comment: Надо выровнять ссылки по левому краю списка? Или по некоей линии справа от картинок? Поясните, что имеется в виду.

Comment: Ответ уже нашёл. Но если вам это ещё интересно. Ссылки нужно выровнять по левому краю (справа от изображений), независимо от размера картинок. Т.е. весь текст должен быть выровнен по одной вертикальной линии.

Comment: Если нашли ответ, то публикуйте его :)

Comment: В общем ответ оказался простым. Нужно обратиться ко всем ссылкам внутри этого списка и применить к ним свойство float. (в моём случае right) Ещё можно поиграться поставив display: block и задать ширину. 

#SELECTOR li a
 {
      padding-right: 1.4em;
      color: #000;
      width: 14em;
      float: right; 
}